# how to set color of rigidarea

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame whose background color is black.

```
setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

I used RigidArea as filter:

```
Component rigidArea = Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20));
rigidArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
getContentPane().add(rigidArea);
```

But this doesn't work, as the rigidArea's color is not black. What's wrong here?

Comment: [`Box.createRigidArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createRigidArea(java.awt.Dimension)) says very simply... *Creates an invisible component that's always the specified size*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried setting the background of the JFrame's content pane to black too?

`getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);`

Comment: Um..it works. What's wrong if I directly use `setBackground(Color.BLACK());` rather than `getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);`

Comment: `setBackground(Color.BLACK());` where does it set the background color?

Comment: you don't directly add widgets to a `JFrame`, you add them to its contentPane which is by default a `JPanel`.

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to though, you could call `JFrame.setContentPane()` and pass it an object that implements the `Container` interface but is transparent.  Then you might be able to call `JFrame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);` and have it do what you're expecting.  Never tried it though.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createRigidArea%28java.awt.Dimension%29), createRigidArea creates an *invisible* component that's always the specified size.

For visible components, you could create a helper method to create a JPanel:

```
JComponent createVisibleComponent(Dimension d) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setMinimumSize(d);
    panel.setMaximumSize(d);
    panel.setPreferredSize(d);

    return panel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply adding a `JPanel` and specify its dimensions?

```
JPanel pan = new JPanel();
pan.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
Dimension d = new Dimension(0,20);
pan.setSize(d);
pan.setPreferredSize(d);
pan.setMaximumSize(d);
pan.setMinimumSize(d);
getContentPane().add(pan);
```